# Swift enum associated value as function argument

Tags: swift, enums

I'm trying to figure out (if possible) how to pass the associated value of an enum to a function, and then switch over the type to execute some specific code.

This works in a playground:

```
struct Bar {}
struct Baz {}

enum Test {
    case foo
    case bar(value: Bar)
    case baz(value: Baz)
}

func doSomething(value: Test) {
    switch value {
        case .foo: print("foo")
        case .bar: print("bar")
        case .baz: print("baz")
    }
}

let bar = Bar()
doSomething(value: .bar(value: bar)) // prints "bar"
doSomething(value: .foo) // prints "foo"
```

But is it possible to pass the associated value directly as an argument? Something like this:

```
let bar = Bar()
doSomething(value: bar)
```

This of course fails because `Bar` is not the same type as `Test`.

How could I do that?

**EDIT**

For clarification, I am currently using overloading, but wanted to see if I could have one central public method which then dispatches to private methods based on the type of the associated value.

Comment: Well, the enum could have two cases, both taking in an associated value of `Bar`. In that case this would be ambiguous wouldn't it?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, hadn't thought of that.

Comment: But Bar is completely independent of Test isn't it?

Comment: Correct, `Bar` (and `Baz`) are independent, and are used elsewhere as well. Just like when `String` would be the associated value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function that takes an `Any` parameter and then try to figure out the type inside by having a switch on supported types but I am not sure it would be better than having separate functions for each type.

```
func doSomething(value: Any) {
    switch value {
    case is Test:
        switch value as? Test {
        case .foo:
            print("foo")
        default:
            print("Not foo")
        }
    case is Bar:
        print("bar")
    case is Baz:
        print("baz")
    default:
        print("Not supported")
    }
}
```

Comment: The `case is Test:` syntax is what I was looking for.

Comment: This is technically true, but terrible. Overloads are how to make use of static typing, here!

Comment: You should switch better without the force cast.

Comment: Still redundantly casting! `case Test.foo: print("foo") case is Test:`

Answer (score 2):

Just provide overloaded function

```
func doSomething(value: Bar) {
    print("bar")
}

doSomething(value: bar) // now works !!
```

Comment: Actually, that's what I currently do - hence my question to see if I can switch within one `doSomething` function.